# how do I solve this error LibGDX Error Stage creation?

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, playing-cards

I created a separate class to call a stage and create it , as advised on a site .
 I have not installed libgdx normally , as I needed to add libgdx to my existing android project , so I have imported the required libraries . 
I created the object of constructor in onCreate method of the AppcompatActivity . 
How do I solve the error ? Should I import more libraries?
Is there any other game engine that can be used, basically I want to make a uno cards game in kotlin . Please Help .

```
//this is the class which creates the stage
class HUD {
    val  stage = Stage(ScreenViewport())
    constructor(){


    }
     //stage create method
    fun create(){
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
        Gdx.graphics.getHeight())
        stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 
        Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }
    //stage render method
    fun render() {
        val delta = Gdx.graphics.deltaTime
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        stage.act(delta)
        stage.draw()
    }
    //stage disposed method
    fun dispose() {
        stage.dispose()
    }
}




//inside other AppCOmpatActivity file 
 val hud : HUD = HUD()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.uno_main)

//        val hud : HUD = HUD()
        hud.create()
        hud.render()
        hud.dispose()
    }


    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for 
    java.nio.ByteBuffer com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.newDisposableByteBuffer(int) (tried Java_com_badlogic_gdx_utils_BufferUtils_newDisposableByteBuffer and Java_com_badlogic_gdx_utils_BufferUtils_newDisposableByteBuffer__I)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.newDisposableByteBuffer(Native Method)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.newUnsafeByteBuffer(BufferUtils.java:517)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexArray.<init>(VertexArray.java:57)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexArray.<init>(VertexArray.java:48)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.<init>(Mesh.java:171)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:101)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.<init>(SpriteBatch.java:78)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:99)
```

Comment: You are missing the native code from the libraries. They must be copied out of the library jar into the appropriate libs directory. You must also call `GdxNativesLoader.load();` before you load anything. And LibGDX is an OpenGL based game engine. You cannot selectively use components from it like this. You must initialize the game engine. This can be done by extending AndroidApplication instead of AppCompatActivity, and calling `initialize()`.

Comment: You will have a very hard time going about it this way. It would be much easier to create a new LibGDX project using your package name and copy your project into the libGDX project. And you will need to read some basic tutorials to be able to use it correctly.